# JPA can't access PostgreSQL due to cast problems

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, jpa, jsf-2

I'm writing a Java ee7 Webapp with PostgreSQL 9.1.1, Glassfish 4, EclipseLink 2. 
My problem is, that I can't access some tables of the database.
I have two (actually 3) entity-classes, which I autogenerated with netbeans from my DB.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "webappuser")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Webappuser.findAll", query = "SELECT w FROM Webappuser w"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Webappuser.findById", query = "SELECT w FROM Webappuser w WHERE w.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Webappuser.findByUsername", query = "SELECT w FROM Webappuser w WHERE w.username = :username"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Webappuser.findByIsadmin", query = "SELECT w FROM Webappuser w WHERE w.isadmin = :isadmin"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Webappuser.findByPassword", query = "SELECT w FROM Webappuser w WHERE w.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Webappuser.findBySalt", query = "SELECT w FROM Webappuser w WHERE w.salt = :salt")})
public class Webappuser implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "isadmin")
    private Boolean isadmin;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 64)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Size(max = 32)
    @Column(name = "salt")
    private String salt;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Collection<Cardbox> cardboxCollection;

    public Webappuser() {
    }

    public Webappuser(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Webappuser(Integer id, String username, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Boolean getIsadmin() {
        return isadmin;
    }

    public void setIsadmin(Boolean isadmin) {
        this.isadmin = isadmin;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getSalt() {
        return salt;
    }

    public void setSalt(String salt) {
        this.salt = salt;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Cardbox> getCardboxCollection() {
        return cardboxCollection;
    }

    public void setCardboxCollection(Collection<Cardbox> cardboxCollection) {
        this.cardboxCollection = cardboxCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Webappuser)) {
            return false;
        }
        Webappuser other = (Webappuser) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.Webappuser[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

d

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cardbox")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cardbox.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Cardbox c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cardbox.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Cardbox c WHERE c.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cardbox.findByCreated", query = "SELECT c FROM Cardbox c WHERE c.created = :created"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cardbox.findByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Cardbox c WHERE c.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cardbox.findByUser", query = "SELECT c FROM Cardbox c WHERE c.user = :user")})
public class Cardbox implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "created")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date created;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @JoinColumn(name = "user", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Webappuser user;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cardbox")
    private Collection<Card> cardCollection;

    public Cardbox() {
    }

    public Cardbox(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Webappuser getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Webappuser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Card> getCardCollection() {
        return cardCollection;
    }

    public void setCardCollection(Collection<Card> cardCollection) {
        this.cardCollection = cardCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Cardbox)) {
            return false;
        }
        Cardbox other = (Cardbox) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.Cardbox[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

I try to access my data with EJBs

```
import entity.Cardbox;
import entity.Webappuser;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Named
@Stateless
public class Dao {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public Collection<Cardbox> getAllCardboxes() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Cardbox.findAll").getResultList();
    }

    public Collection<Cardbox> getAllCardboxByUser() {
        Webappuser user = em.createNamedQuery("Webappuser.findByUsername", Webappuser.class)
                .setParameter("username", "haha")
                .getSingleResult();
        return em.createNamedQuery("Cardbox.findByUser", Cardbox.class)
                .setParameter("user", user).getResultList();
    }

    //This works
    public Webappuser getAllUser() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Webappuser.findByUsername", Webappuser.class)
                .setParameter("username", "haha")
                .getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Access via JSF

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{dao.allCardboxes}" var="cardbox">
            <h:column>#{cardbox.name}</h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

    <h:dataTable value="#{dao.allCardboxByUser}" var="cardboxOfUser">
            <h:column>#{cardboxOfUser.id}</h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

    <h:dataTable value="#{dao.allUser}" var="user">
            <h:column>#{user.username}</h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
 </h:form>
```

Errors I get with ´dao.allCardboxes´ (Had to leave to top part out, due to too many characters)

```
javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy526.getAllCardboxes(Unknown Source)
    at ejb.__EJB31_Generated__Dao__Intf____Bean__.getAllCardboxes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-3001] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [postgres], of class [class java.lang.String], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Integer].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "postgres"
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:479)
    at ejb.Dao.getAllCardboxes(Dao.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor153.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-3001] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [postgres], of class [class java.lang.String], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Integer].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "postgres"
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException.couldNotBeConverted(ConversionException.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObjectToInteger(ConversionManager.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObject(ConversionManager.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourcePlatform.convertObject(DatasourcePlatform.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.extractPrimaryKeyFromRow(ObjectBuilder.java:2805)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.extractPrimaryKeyFromExpression(ObjectBuilder.java:2651)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.checkCacheForObject(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.checkEarlyReturnLocal(ReadObjectQuery.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkEarlyReturn(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:836)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.NoIndirectionPolicy.valueFromQuery(NoIndirectionPolicy.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRowInternal(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2234)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.valueFromRowInternal(OneToOneMapping.java:1790)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRow(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2120)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1455)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:862)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneNormally(ObjectBuilder.java:777)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadAllQuery.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:468)
    ... 103 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "postgres"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObjectToInteger(ConversionManager.java:527)
    ... 142 more
```

Errors I get with ´dao.allCardboxByUser´

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: Operator existiert nicht: name = integer
  Hinweis: Kein Operator stimmt mit dem angegebenen Namen und den Argumenttypen überein. Sie müssen möglicherweise ausdrückliche Typumwandlungen hinzufügen.
  Position: 57
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT id, created, name, user FROM cardbox WHERE (user = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Cardbox.findByUser" referenceClass=Cardbox sql="SELECT id, created, name, user FROM cardbox WHERE (user = ?)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:377)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor153.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: Operator existiert nicht: name = integer
  Hinweis: Kein Operator stimmt mit dem angegebenen Namen und den Argumenttypen überein. Sie müssen möglicherweise ausdrückliche Typumwandlungen hinzufügen.
  Position: 57
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT id, created, name, user FROM cardbox WHERE (user = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Cardbox.findByUser" referenceClass=Cardbox sql="SELECT id, created, name, user FROM cardbox WHERE (user = ?)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1995)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2714)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2667)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    ... 104 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: Operator existiert nicht: name = integer
  Hinweis: Kein Operator stimmt mit dem angegebenen Namen und den Argumenttypen überein. Sie müssen möglicherweise ausdrückliche Typumwandlungen hinzufügen.
  Position: 57
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:641)
    ... 124 more
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="CardMKNPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>flashMKN</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: How about your connection settings? for example persistence.xml file. Looks like you have misplaced your db name 'postgres' with the db-port!

Comment: How can I look this up? I let netbeans do everything with the DB.

Comment: Funny thing is that I can list all cardboxes if I let netbeans create the JSF, EJB and controllers? Rightclick on project -> create JSF from entity classes. Is something wrong with my Dao class?

Comment: There should be a file named persistence.xml inside your meta-inf folder. If not, then search the file inside your source folder, usually its "src" at where you have saved the project.

Comment: How about now? Is something wrong with my persistence.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your name query("Cardbox.findByUser") should be like below. Currently you are using another object in where condition instead of a field.

```
SELECT c FROM cardbox c WHERE c.user.username = :user
```

Here c.user represents the Entity Webappuser which has the field username.

Comment: Worked, but why doens't ´SELECT c FROM cardbox c WHERE c.user.id = :id´ work?